# Back Button on Camera Crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camera

I have been looking at various solutions on Stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. I am having a problem where when a user initiates a camera and then presses the "back" button to cancel out of the camera, the app crashes. I thought this piece of code below was what would solve the problem but doesn't seem to work.

```
else if (resultCode== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        println("result cancelled")
        return
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var btn: Button? = null
    private var imageview: ImageView? = null
    private val GALLERY = 1
    private val CAMERA = 2

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

        btn = findViewById<View>(R.id.btn) as Button
        imageview = findViewById<View>(R.id.iv) as ImageView

        val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)

        var listImages : Array<File>? = null
        listImages = wallpaperDirectory.listFiles()

        if(listImages != null && listImages.size!! > 0){

//            iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listImages[0].absolutePath))
            val img2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listImages[0].absolutePath)
            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, img2)
            round.isCircular = true
            iv.setImageDrawable(round)

        }
        else {
            val img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.profile_image)
            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, img)
            round.isCircular = true
            iv.setImageDrawable(round)
            println("hit hit hit")

        }

        btn!!.setOnClickListener { showPictureDialog() }
    }

    private fun showPictureDialog() {
        val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action")
        val pictureDialogItems = arrayOf("Select Photo From Gallery", "Capture Photo From Camera")
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems
        ) { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> choosePhotoFromGallary()
                1 -> takePhotoFromCamera()
            }
        }
        pictureDialog.show()
    }

    fun choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
    }

    fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA)
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data: Intent?) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == GALLERY)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                val contentURI = data.data
                try
                {
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, contentURI)
                    val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, bitmap)
                    round.isCircular = true

                    val path = saveImage(bitmap)
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    imageview!!.setImageDrawable(round)

                }
                catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA)
        {
            val thumbnail = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            val round = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(resources, thumbnail)
            round.isCircular = true
            imageview!!.setImageDrawable(round)
            saveImage(thumbnail)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        else if (resultCode== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))

            println("result cancelled")


        }
    }

    fun saveImage(myBitmap: Bitmap):String {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes)
        val wallpaperDirectory = File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY)
        wallpaperDirectory.deleteRecursively()

        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        Log.d("fee",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
        {

            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs()
        }

        try
        {
            Log.d("heel",wallpaperDirectory.toString())
            val f = File(wallpaperDirectory, ((Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis()).toString() + ".jpg"))
            f.createNewFile()
            val fo = FileOutputStream(f)
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    arrayOf(f.getPath()),
                    arrayOf("image/jpeg"), null)
            fo.close()
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath())

            return f.getAbsolutePath()
        }
        catch (e1: IOException) {
            e1.printStackTrace()
        }

        return ""
    }

    companion object {
        private val IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts"

    }
}
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--        android:text="Select or Capture Image" -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:width="2dp"
        android:background="#00000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/profile_image" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Error Log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.pickimagetakeexamples/com.example.pickimagetakeexamples.MainActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.pickimagetakeexamples.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:124)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4994)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Post stacktrace

Comment: Can you post your error log ?

Comment: Please see above; error log has been placed. The error at   at com.example.pickimagetakeexamples.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:124) is at the val thumbnal under requestCode == Camera

Comment: @rengineer according to the info you provided it seems like the data is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logs I can say that The reason behind crashing the app is, you are not capturing the image and you are pressing the back button, which returns null as data to your onActivityResult, you need to specify what to do if null as a result returns in your onActivityResult. Just add default parameter or if data==null and handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should add if condition.

The camera opens and user returns back. Calls onActivityResult() with resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED. Likewise user takes a photo from camera. Calls onActivityResult with resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK.

You checked RequestCode in if conditions but didn't ResultCode. Change your if conditions below:

```
if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode && requestCode == GALLERY)
if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode && requestCode == CAMERA)
```